# Jquery switch active class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to addClass and removeClass to the div`mall_alldeal_cat_active` , to point the alphabet that selected. However when I click one of the alphabet all div addClass show up together. Anyone able to help me check what mistake I have made ?

```js
$('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var $this = $('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li div'); 
 $('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li div').removeClass('mall_alldeal_cat_active');
 $this.addClass('mall_alldeal_cat_active');
  
});
```

```css
.mall_alldeal_cat_title{
 background:#fff;
 padding-left:30px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.mall_alldeal_cat_title li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px 10px 5px 10px;
 cursor:pointer; 

}
.mall_alldeal_cat_active{
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid black;
 position:absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mall_alldeal_cat_title">
                     <li>A<div class="mall_alldeal_cat_active"></div></li>
                        <li>B<div class=""></div></li>
                        <li>C<div class=""></div></li>
                        <li>D<div class=""></div></li>
                    </div>
```

Comment: li should not contain div....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `this`, which is the `li` you clicked, then find the `div` inside it.

`var $this = $('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li div');` still match all the div elements inside `.mall_alldeal_cat_title`.

```js
$('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li div').removeClass('mall_alldeal_cat_active');
 $(this).find('div').addClass('mall_alldeal_cat_active');
  
});
```

```css
.mall_alldeal_cat_title{
 background:#fff;
 padding-left:30px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.mall_alldeal_cat_title li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px 10px 5px 10px;
 cursor:pointer; 

}
.mall_alldeal_cat_active{
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid black;
 position:absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mall_alldeal_cat_title">
                     <li>A<div class="mall_alldeal_cat_active"></div></li>
                        <li>B<div class=""></div></li>
                        <li>C<div class=""></div></li>
                        <li>D<div class=""></div></li>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is selecting all the `li` elements. Try something like this to get the `li` siblings and remove their classes, and only add it to the current one.

```js
$('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var $this = $(this);
 $this.siblings().find('div').removeClass('mall_alldeal_cat_active');
 $this.find('div').addClass('mall_alldeal_cat_active');
  
});
```

```css
.mall_alldeal_cat_title{
 background:#fff;
 padding-left:30px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.mall_alldeal_cat_title li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px 10px 5px 10px;
 cursor:pointer; 

}
.mall_alldeal_cat_active{
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid black;
 position:absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mall_alldeal_cat_title">
                     <li>A<div class="mall_alldeal_cat_active"></div></li>
                        <li>B<div class=""></div></li>
                        <li>C<div class=""></div></li>
                        <li>D<div class=""></div></li>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) .

This code help you.

```
$('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //var $this = $('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li div');  
        $('.mall_alldeal_cat_title li div').removeClass('mall_alldeal_cat_active');
        $(this).children().addClass('mall_alldeal_cat_active');
    });
```